# Why isn't this jquery script looping through HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to loop through a series of HTML elements conditional on mouse click ie the sequence of events are:
1. display element inside div
2. click on div
3. display next element
4. click
5. display next element
....etc
6. loop from final element back to first element

I've created the following code but the next element eg id="image" does not replace the current element.  Why is that? See HTML, CSS and JS below.

```
<div class="frame" id="title">CULTURAL</div>
<div class="frame" id="image">
    <img class="topLeft" src="images/zanzibar_market_1.jpg" alt="Zanzibar Cloth">
</div>
<div class="frame" id="text">A culture encompasses the ideas, customs, and social behaviour of a people or society.
    When we mix with other cultures we are enriched by the experience.  We know more of the world.</div>

.frame {
    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid skyblue;
}
#title {
    font-size: 2em;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
#image {
    opacity: 0.0;
}
#text {
     opacity: 0.0;
 }

var frames = document.getElementsByClassName("frame");

for( var i=0; i<frames.length; i++ ){
    $("frames".eq(i)).click (function() {
        $("frames".eq(i)).animate({
            opacity: 0.0
        });
        var x = i + 1;
        $("frames".eq(x)).animate({
            opacity: 1.0
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These selectors are wrong:

```
$("frames".eq(i))...
$("frames".eq(x))...
```

should be:

```
$(".frame").eq(i)...
$(".frame").eq(x)...
```

And your logic for the last element is missing. You can try something like:

```
var x = (i + 1) % frames.length;
```

Comment: And it's actually `.frame`, not `frames`.

Comment: I now have:var frames = document.getElementsByClassName("frame");

for( var i=0; i<frames.length; i++ ){
    $(".frame").eq(i).click (function() {
        $(".frame").eq(i).animate({
            opacity: 0.0
        });
        var x = i + 1;
        $(".frame").eq(x).animate({
            opacity: 1.0
        });
    });
};

Comment: Thanks Shomz. What does   var x = (i + 1) % frames.length;   mean? specifically the % sign in this context.

Comment: You're welcome.`%` is a modulo operator - calculates a remainder of a division operation. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()

Comment: That code I wrote makes sure that `x` stays between 0 and the number of frames minus one.